# Generate Page Based on JSON Data

Tags: json, angularjs, firebase

I'm using AngularJS for an app I'm building and was wondering if it's possible to generate pages when items are pushed to a JSON object called `places`. Each item when pushed is given a unique ID and I figured I could use this id (e.g. 123456) as part of the url like so `site.com/places/123456`.

```
{
  "places" : [
    {
      "id" : 471756,
      "title" : "The Whittington Hospital"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is it possible to have this page generated automatically (for example, based on a template)?

I ask because I'm trying to build an app that let's users create their own hospitals via a form. Once a hospital is created and pushed to the JSON object, I'd like a page to be created for that hospital.

Can I use Angular for this? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

Still having a bit of trouble with this. Here's what I've got so far.

**place.html**

```
<div ng-controller='PlaceCtrl'>
  <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
app.constant('FBURL', 'https://luminous-fire-8685.firebaseio.com/');

app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/places/:placeId', {
      templateUrl: 'views/place.html',
      controller: 'PlaceCtrl'
    })
}]);

app.factory('place', function($firebase, FBURL, $routeParams) {
  var ref = new Firebase(FBURL + "places/" + $routeParams.placeId);

  return {
    id: $routeParams.placeId
  }
});

app.controller('PlaceCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, FBURL, $firebase, $location, $routeParams, place) {
  $scope.placeId = place.id;
});
```

Comment: Yes... just create a standard template? Use `{{}}` to send the data to the view

Comment: @tymeJV Can you point me in the direction of some documentation for this? Also, how big can an Angular app be? Is there a limit, or a cutoff where you should use Rails/PHP instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for ngRoute and `$routeProvider`. With those you can set up a parameterized route like this:

```
.when('/place/:placeId', { templateUrl: 'place.html', controller: 'PlaceCtrl' })
```

So every time a visitor hits a URL that starts with `/place/` it ends up at `PlaceCtrl` and `place.html`. And the place ID is passed as a parameter.

Then you can pick up the parameter in your controller:

```
app.controller('PlaceCtrl', function($scope, FBURL, $firebase, $routeParams) {
    var ref = new Firebase(FBURL+"places/"+$routeParams.placeId);
```

See also:

- My sample application that uses AngularJS, Firebase and AngularFire: https://github.com/puf/trenches/blob/master/app.js (from which I copy/paste/modified the above snippets)
- The [AngularJS documentation for `routeParams`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams)
- The [AngularJS tutorial's step on routing](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07)
- The (way better) [Thinkster.io tutorial page on routeParams](https://thinkster.io/egghead/routeparams-api/)

Comment: This is massively helpful. Sorry for the late response. Going to dive into trying this out, right away!

Comment: I've added an update to my question. I've been using your sample app as a reference here, but I can't seem to get the `{{ title }}` to display on the relevant page. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You `PlaceCtrl` is only binding a `placeId` to the scope, so there is no `title` in scope to display in the view. You can easily debug this type of thing yourself by using the Angular devtools in Chrome.

Comment: So would returning a `title: $routeParams.placeTitle` and then making `place.title` available to the scope with `$scope.placeTitle = place.title;` do the trick? I'll take a look at Angular devtools too!

Comment: This `var links = $firebase(ref.child('links')).$asObject();` let's me access my links on the page like so `{{ links.web }}`, but `var title = $firebase(ref.child('title'));` doesn't let me print to the page with `{{ title }}`. Basically `.$asObject()` and `.$asArray()` work, but how do I retrieve data if it's not in an object or an array?

Comment: Please start a new question for this, as it is unrelated to routing. Be sure to include all the necessary information in your new question (but nothing more).

Comment: Sure thing! I've just posted the new question over here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26810741/add-data-to-scope-from-firebase