# Add Data to .$scope from Firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I'm currently trying to print data on a page from my Firebase. I'm using `$routeProvider` so it shows the relevant data for the relevant page.

My Firebase data looks like this:

```
{
  "providers" : {
    "0" : {
      "title" : "The Whittington Hospital",
      "address" : {
        "street" : "Magdala Ave"
      },
      "links" : {
        "web" : "http://whittington.nhs.uk"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My **HTML** like this:

```
<div ng-controller='ProviderCtrl'>
    <h4>at {{ title }}</h4>
    <address>
      {{ address.street }}<br>
    </address>
    <p><a target="blank" ng-href="{{ links.web }}">{{ links.web }}</a></p>
</div>
```

And my **JS** like this:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/providers/:providerId', {
      templateUrl: 'views/provider.html',
      controller: 'ProviderCtrl'
    })
}]);

app.factory('provider', function($firebase, FBURL, $routeParams) {
  var ref = new Firebase(FBURL + "providers/" + $routeParams.providerId);

  var links = $firebase(ref.child('links')).$asObject();
  var address = $firebase(ref.child('address')).$asObject();
  var title = $firebase(ref.child('title'));

  return {
    ref: ref,
    id: $routeParams.providerId,
    links: links,
    address: address,
    title: title
  }
});

app.controller('ProviderCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, FBURL, $firebase, $location, $routeParams, provider) {
  $scope.providerId = provider.id;
  $scope.links = provider.links;
  $scope.address = provider.address;
  $scope.title = provider.title;
});
```

The problem I'm having is `{{ links.web }}` works, so does `{{ address.street }}` etc. But for some reason `{{ title }}` doesn't work. I'm sure this has something to do with the fact that I'm calling `$asObject()` on those objects. The thing is, `title` isn't an object, it's just an ordinary string.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong here. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: A string is also an object. Did you try calling asObject on it?

Comment: When I call `asObject()` on it. It prints open and closed curly braces like this `{}` to the page.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Is `var title` looking for the child of `title`, or looking for a child of `providers` called `title`? Perhaps, that is it?